# It is normal to receive a business card during a c-suite interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I recently had an in person interview with a group of 6 senior level members. I received a business card from one of the senior level members mid interview, never experienced that so not sure if that’s a good or bad sign. Also I did receive an office tour after my interview. Are this signs that I will potentially get an offer?

Comment: *"Also I did receive an office your after my interview"* - I'm afraid I don't understand this part, mind clarifying?

Comment: Different people do things different ways. Executives are people too.

Comment: @DarkCygnus "office tour" I think

Comment: **not sure if that’s a good or bad sign** - It's not any kind of sign. Someone gave you their business card. Don't analyze it. People give other people their business card millions of times every day. Stop trying to "read the tea leaves". Not everything has to mean "something".

Comment: @KeithMiller yeah surely that, as the "y" is next to the "t" ...

Answer (score 6):

> I received a business card from one of the senior level members mid interview, never experienced that so not sure if that’s a good or bad sign. [...] Are this signs that I will potentially get an offer?

Impossible to tell, we would be guessing.

Depending on the industry/business type, it can be more/less common to use business cards. For example getting one from a lawyer or someone from a bank would not be rare to me, nor getting one from a graphic designer perhaps, but perhaps getting one from a Developer could be more rare (I am a software developer/engineer and I *do* have business cards, so perhaps I'm a bit of an outlier?).

However, all in all, this seems to me like a nice gesture and gives me "good vibes" (seems encouraging would be a more professional word), so to say...

Now, even though this seems encouraging **don't hold your breath for this offer**. Continue applying until you land an offer and sign it. Only then you can be completely sure that you are safe.

Good luck job-hunting :)